# Magento 2, google API, making custom sql query

Tags: magento2, blocks, sql

Below sql statement finds the closest 20 locations within a radius of 25 kilometers to the -33, 151 coordinate.

```
SELECT id, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

I Wondering how to write the query in below?

```
protected function getConnection()
    {
        if (!$this->connection) {
            $this->connection = $this->_resource->getConnection('core_write');
        }
        return $this->connection;
    }
    public function getSearchQuery($lat,$lng)
    {
        $table=$this->_resource->getTableName('my_search_map_table');
        // sql query here?

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right query was:

```
$select = $this->getConnection()->select()
        ->from( ['sm' => 'my_search_map_table'],
                ['id',
                'distance' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(
                    "( 6371 * acos( cos( radians($lat) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng )" .
                    " - radians($lng) ) + sin( radians($lat) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) )")
                ])
        ->having('distance < 25')
        ->order('distance')
        ->limit(20);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public function getSearchQuery($lat, $lng)
    {
        $table = $this->_resource->getTableName('my_search_map_table');

        $lat = $this->getConnection()->quote($lat);
        $lng = $this->getConnection()->quote($lng);


        return $this->getConnection()->select()
            ->from($table, [
                'id',
                'distance' => new \Zend_Db_Expr(
                    "( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( $lat ) ) * cos( radians( $lng )" .
                        " - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( $lat ) ) ) )"

                )
            ])->having('distance < 25')
            ->order('distance')
            ->limit(20);
    }
```